# Report Viewer and MS Access Error

Tags: vb.net, ms-access, reportviewer

```
Public Class GenerateReport
     Private Sub GenerateReport_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
          'TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'CMPDataSet.Items' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
          Me.ItemsTableAdapter.Fill(Me.CMPDataSet.Items)
          Me.ReportViewer1.RefreshReport()
     End Sub
End Class
```

It is giving me an error which says `Not a valid file name` in `Me.ItemsTableAdapter.Fill(Me.CMPDataSet.Items)`. Can somebody explain why?

Comment: First of all, what are the types ItemTableAdapter and CMPDataset (which i presume isn't an ordinary dataset)

Comment: Sorry but It's my first time using this report viewer. Those codes are generated by the report viewer.